# C# - replace every primitive with a hash in a JSON document

Tags: c#, json, regex, security, json.net

I want to improve diagnosis of JSON serialization issues, and for that I want the subsystem to emit the structure of a JSON document whenever some exception appears. This is supposed to run only at test environments, but it's governed by a flag, and I'm concerned that it might be too easy to change the flag or forget to restore it, potentially causing leaks at production.

As a mitigation technique, I want to replace every value that appears after the field name with a secure hash. After all, most of issues are not content related, but structure related (fields with wrong casing, missing fields, etc).

Is there some reliable method to iterate over all leaf-nodes of a JSON that represent values, and replace them with something else? That would make me sleep better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the existing JSON to a `JToken` and then replace all the descendant `JValues` with hashes.  I would create a couple of helper methods like this:

```
public static string ObscureJson(string json)
{
    if (json == null) return null;

    JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
    using (HashAlgorithm hashAlgo = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        JContainer container = token as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
        {
            foreach (JValue value in container.Descendants().OfType<JValue>().ToList())
            {
                value.Replace(HashJValue(value, hashAlgo));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            token = HashJValue((JValue)token, hashAlgo);
        }
        return token.ToString();    
    }
}

public static JValue HashJValue(JValue val, HashAlgorithm hashAlgo)
{
    if (val == null || val.Type == JTokenType.Null) return val;

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val.ToString());
    byte[] hash = hashAlgo.ComputeHash(buffer);
    string hex = string.Join("", hash.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
    return new JValue(hex);
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
string redactedJson = ObscureJson(originalJson);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8VJpJl

I'm not sure you really need the hashes, though, to be honest.  If your goal is to obscure the values to prevent accidental exposure, then replacing them with a simple `X` would leak less information, and would avoid bloating the JSON.